Keychain SecItemCopyMatching returning -25300(item not found) after first application run
I have a project with a lot of targets, one of this target is a framework that is responsible of all keychain operations.
When app is launched at first time all keychain operative works like a charm, but at second time, any data can't be recovered from keychain as SecItemCopyMatching returns -25300.
Another hint is that this only happens using real iPhone.
Should I activate keychain sharing capability? I think no because only one target of the is accessing keychain.
I am using SecItemCopyMatching with the following attributes:
kSecReturnData = kCFBooleanTrue
kSecMatchLimit = kSecMatchLimitOne
kSecClass = kSecClassGenericPassword
kSecAttrService = "service name"
kSecAttrAccount = "account name"

Please any hint is welcome!
